# Angular 6 z-index and animation issues

Tags: angular, css-animations, z-index

I have this code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1ctge

with the following Font Awesome icon code (for angular using FortAwesome)

```
<fa-icon [icon]='["fas","cogs"]' spin size='4x' style='z-index: 100; top: 10px; left: 60 px;'></fa-icon>
```

I am trying to get the cogs to spin and the cogs to float over the content.

I am stuck.

Any input would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `fa-icon` component spin you must add `[spin]="true"` as mentionned in [the @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome).

The cogs spinning wont look as you would expect, it will spin the whole icon as one image, to make the cogs spin individually you have to create multiple spinning icons with the right size and at the right position.

The z-index has no effect if the position is not absolute.

I suggest this code as starting solution :

```
<div style='position: absolute; z-index: 100; top: 50%; left: 40%;'>
  <fa-icon [icon]='["fas","cog"]' [spin]="true" size='4x'></fa-icon>
  <fa-icon [icon]='["fas","cog"]' [spin]="true" size='2x'></fa-icon>
</div>
```

[Here is an edit of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52843500)

Comment: I think I've got it with this code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxmtys

I just need to figure out how to hide it and show it as the data is loading.:D

Comment: An ngIf would do the trick a guess. You may want to consider a backdrop to avoid user interaction with components while processing.

Comment: I understand the *ngIf, but how would I do the backdrop?

Comment: Something like this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52843500-2
click the cogs to stop loading.

Comment: That seems to be what I want, but I need it to trigger the cogs after the selection has been made and the data is loading into the fields (<mat-form-field>) of the div below it, the *element* div .  Thanks so much for your help here.

Comment: I would try to make an observable for that. As this is starting to become out of the initial question scope I suggest creating a new question for that :).

Comment: Will do.  I will open another question.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for you help again.  I've since been editing the code, and I think I've setup a pretty good data service for my app, but I wanted you input on it.  It does seem to run the cogs until the data gets loaded, but do you have any further input?  Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ek8kh1

Answer (score 0):

you need to change that to:

```
<fa-icon [icon]='["fas","cogs"]' size='4x' class="fa-spin" style='z-index: 100; top: 10px; left: 60 px; position: absolute;'></fa-icon>
```

class fa-spin is needed to spin the icon, but i guess you will need another icon, as the whole icon is spinning, and you probably wanted them to spin seperately. (not absolutely sure about that, never done anything with font awesome)

also i hope the absolut positioning is what you meant with float on content